# Android Compose Tutorial error in MaterialTheme.shapes.medium

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial in the Shape section follows the code:

```
// ...
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface

 @Composable
 fun MessageCard(msg: Message) {
 Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 8.dp)) {
   Image(
       painter = painterResource(R.drawable.profile_picture),
       contentDescription = null,
       modifier = Modifier
           .size(40.dp)
           .clip(CircleShape)
           .border(1.5.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary, CircleShape)
   )
   Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))

   Column {
       Text(
           text = msg.author,
           color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary,
           style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall
       )

       Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))

       Surface(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium, shadowElevation = 1.dp) {
           Text(
               text = msg.body,
               modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 4.dp),
               style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium
           )
       }
   }
}
```

**MaterialTheme.shapes.medium** does not exist. I think there is an error in the tutorial
do you know to make the tutorial compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the tutorial seems to be using material2, not material3 (which you're using), and as mentioned in the
[migration guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material2-material3#shape) the MaterialTheme.shapes property doesn't include a medium shape like it did in Material Design 2. Instead, you'll need to define your own shape. (or just downgrade the depencies to be using Material2)